Calculate the variance of linearization coefficientes
Suppose you have two vectors, call them $x,y \in {R}^+$, and you want to apply a non-linear  formula in order to estimate $(a,b)$ coefficients following that:
$$y = \dfrac{ax}{x+b}$$
So, in order to do this, you apply a linearization (or linear transformation) like inverse and now the prior equation can be though as:
$$\dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{b}{a}\Big(\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)$$
$$\nu = \beta_0 + \beta_1\mu$$
Where $\nu = \dfrac{1}{y}$, $\mu = \dfrac{1}{x}$, $\beta_0 = \dfrac{1}{a}$ and $\beta_1 = \dfrac{b}{a}$. In this way, now you can easily calculate the coefficients since:
$$a = \dfrac{1}{\beta_0}, b=\dfrac{\beta_1}{\beta_0}$$
I know I have calculated $V(\beta_i)$ with the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, but what about $V(a)$ or $V(B)$? Can I apply the same transformation to calculate it? maybe like:
$$V(a) = 1/V(\beta_0)$$
